# struts2 dojo datepicker not working fine in Internet explorer

Tags: browser, datepicker

i am using a dojo datepicker in my jsp page (struts2 tags).I am using tomcat 7.0.23.when i run the code i am able to see the datepicker in both firefox and internet explorer but when i deployed the same code on linux server(apache-tomcat-6.0.14) datepicker is visible in firefox but in i.e only label(Start Date/endDate) of datepickers are shown no textfield and calendar icon is shown.I have tried with apache-tomcat-7.0.25 on the server but get the same result.please find below a part of jsp file.

```
s:form name="summaryForm" action="SummaryTrans">
<sx:datetimepicker name="startDate"   label="Start Date" endDate="yesterdayDate"  displayFormat="dd-MMM-yy" value="yesterdayDate"/>
<sx:datetimepicker name="endDate" label="End Date" endDate="yesterdayDate"  displayFormat="dd-MMM-yy" value="yesterdayDate"/>
```

Please help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have `<sx:head>` in your head segment of jsp. That is mandatory.